# wp_util loaded before underscore causing error in WordPress Woocommerce frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Working on a client site and suddenly an error comes up - Cannot add a variant product to the cart, keep saying "Please select some product options before adding this product to your basket." eventhough one of the option was chosen.
[the dev website product link here](https://rickyschembri.concentricdigital.com.au/?product=the-tree&v=3a1ed7090bfa)

Saw the JS error on console "wp-util.min.js?ver=5.7.2:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined" and realise it's a script enqueue error, as underscore should be enqueued before wp-util.
I can do everything just fine if I have logged in as admin, and the underscore is enqueued before wp-util.

How can I fix this error?Is there a way to debug the enqueued order? Tried to add wp_enqueue_script to childtheme style enqueue handle, and changed the add_action priority to highest (i.e. 0) but that could not fix it.
How can I ensure underscore loaded before wp-util?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'suffice_child_enqueue_child_styles' ) ) {
function customizr_child_enqueue_child_styles() {
    // loading parent style
    wp_register_style(
      'parente2-style',
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
    );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parente2-style' );
    // loading child style
    wp_register_style(
      'childe2-style',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'childe2-style');
    //enqueue underscore
    wp_enqueue_script( 'underscore' );
  }
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customizr_child_enqueue_child_styles',0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

From wp_localize_script docs:

**IMPORTANT! wp_localize_script() MUST be called after the script it's being attached to has been registered using wp_register_script() or wp_enqueue_script().**

So, first load yours scripts and then load wp-util.

```
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'jsVars', [ 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ], [ 'wp-util' ] );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-util' );
```